# How to load assembly from path in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, .net-assembly

The `Assembly` class in `UWP` has only `Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)`.
How can I load an assembly if I have only its physical location (relative or absolute, doesn't matter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.
You can only load an assembly from your appxpackage using the assembly name.
Loading assemblies from a path is not allowed/supported by the UWP/WinRT API.

```
var asName      = new AssemblyName();
asName.Name     = "assembly name";
var a           = Assembly.Load(asName);
var type        = a.GetType("name of the type to load");

return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: To get things straight:
In order to make my assembly loadable in the runtime I have to do the following:
1) Declare it inside the appxpackage using its name. How is this done? Do you have any sample?
2) Run the code you provided using the specified name.
3) Sit back and enjoy

Comment: To declare your assembly in the appxpackage, the easiest way is to add it as a dependency of your application. Every library declared in the application "references" will be added to the appxpackage

Comment: Cool. What about implicit dependencies. i.e. the ones that are not added to the references' collection?

Comment: I guess you should add them too. It should be safer.

Comment: I've added some libraries and there was not change in the contents of appxmanifest file. Can you point me to the manual way of adding assemblies?

Comment: Please vote for this feature where I have requested that Microsoft add a feature to UWP so that this can be made possible. https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/18145291-dynamically-load-assembly